# Newton's Sums might be helpful but a bit long.

Tags: polynomials, summation

I tried this question with basic Newton's Sums approach but it was kinda long.

Can anyone post a bit smaller and logical method ?

---

Consider the polynomial $$P(x)=6x^5+5x^4+4x^3+3x^2+2x+1$$ 
Given that $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}$ and $x_{5}$ are roots of $P(x)$, calculate $\displaystyle \sum^{5}_{h=0} \sum_{\text{cyc}}\left(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}x_{4}\right)^h$

$\text{Details }:\displaystyle \sum_{\text{cyc}}$ denotes cyclic summation.

Comment: maybe [Vieta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) can be useful?

Comment: Never mind. I read it carelessly and thought that the polynomial had degree six. So I was worried about not all permutations appearing.

Answer (score 2):

Define a modified equation:
$$Q(y)=y^5P\left(\frac1y\right)=y^5+2y^4+3y^3+4y^2+5y+6$$
Roots of $Q(y)=0$ are inverse of roots of $P(x)=0$.
Then we use the Newton's sums:
\begin{align}
&Q_1=\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x_i}\\
&Q_2=\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x_i^2}\\
&Q_3=\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x_i^3}\\
&Q_4=\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x_i^4}\\
&Q_5=\sum_{cyc}\frac1{x_i^5}\\
&Q_1+2=0\\
&Q_2+2Q_1+3\cdot2=0\\
&Q_3+2Q_2+3Q_1+4\cdot3=0\\
&Q_4+2Q_3+3Q_2+4Q_1+5\cdot4=0\\
&Q_5+2Q_4+3Q_3+4Q_2+5Q_1+6\cdot5=0\\
\end{align}
And we can get all $Q_n$'s. We also know from the Vieta's formula that $p=x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=-\frac16$. Then we can compute
$$\sum_{h=0}^5\sum_{cyc}(x_ix_jx_kx_l)^h=\sum_{h=0}^5p^h\times Q_h$$
($Q_0=5$.)